# Sending text input to google assistant in windows 10

Tags: python, google-api, google-assistant

OK, first off, the main idea here is to automate some light switches upon arrival. I live in a neck of the woods that confuses gps, so my arrival functions for tuya and etc do not work reliably as expected. They do work sometimes but I need it to be reliable.

So the plan was to install google assistant sdk and get textinput working. Downloaded and installed everything and did the google cloud platform thing and everything is working great. I can type "turn off the bedroom light" in cmd and the bedroom light turns off. Now, this works great, don't get me wrong, and I can most likely adapt this to work for what I need. But this requires to boot up an interactive console and then physically type the phrase I want to ask.

The solution to this problem would be if I could query textinput with something like

`py -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.textinput --device-id "insert_device_id" --device-model-id "insert_device_model_id" --textquery "turn off the bedroom light"`

Then I wouldn't have to boot an interactive prompt and exit it manually. I would like to just be able to send text to the assistant without interacting at all with google assistant.

The end goal is to use my computer to ping my cell phones static ip address, and turn on devices/lights via google assistant on pc.

Comment: It would be quite easy to edit [this sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py) to replace the interactive part with taking command line parameters. What have you tried so far?

Comment: ive tried making a post on stackoverflow, cmon what did you expect? LOL

jokes aside, I have not tried anything yet because I was uncertain that it was possible. So what you are saying is that it would be trivial to modify the sample code to bypass the interactive shell, and just get results or do actions? Also, thank you for taking your time to help.

Comment: i found a work around using a text to speech online tool and by using the pushtotalk '-I' option. So far it pings the phone and if it detects it, it will check the status of the light and if its off, it turns it on. State of the art technology here right?

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started, this is an alternative based on the [sample source code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py):

```
# Add along with other click.options
@click.option('--textquery',
              metavar='<text to send>',
              required=False,
              help=(('Text to send. If not specified, use interactive mode')))

# Next add the flag to main
def main(api_endpoint, credentials,
         device_model_id, device_id, lang, display, verbose,
         grpc_deadline, textquery, *args, **kwargs):

# Then the main loop
with SampleTextAssistant(lang, device_model_id, device_id, display,
                         grpc_channel, grpc_deadline) as assistant:
    while True:
        # If textquery data set, use that as the query
        if textquery:
            query = textquery
        else:
            query = click.prompt('')
        click.echo('<you> %s' % query)
        response_text, response_html = assistant.assist(text_query=query)
        if display and response_html:
            system_browser = browser_helpers.system_browser
            system_browser.display(response_html)
        if response_text:
            click.echo('<@assistant> %s' % response_text)
        # If we're doing text, quit the loop
        if textquery:
            break
```

Totally untested, though, but hopefully you get the idea!